# Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Не запускается отладчик в Android Studio.
Устройство для отладки - смартфон, подключенный через USB.
Build Variant - debug.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
```

Отладка через USB включена и разрешена на устройстве, adb успешно запускается, смартфон распознаётся.
Приложение успешно запускается и работает на устройстве, но отладчик не подключается, генерируя следующий лог:

```
install successfully finished in 1 s 750 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.nikmax.myapplication/com.nikmax.myapplication.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.nikmax.myapplication | com.nikmax.myapplication.test
    ...
Waiting for application to come online: com.nikmax.myapplication | com.nikmax.myapplication.test

Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session.
```

Перезапуск adb НЕ решает проблему, перезапуск студии и пересборка проекта НЕ решают проблему.

Attach Debugger to Android process также не работает - кнопка OK заблокирована (приложение в этот момент работает на устройстве):
[image: скриншот]

Бьюсь уже целый день, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Проект новый или старый? Попробуйте создать новый хелло-ворлд и на нём потестить - если подключится, то надо чистить проект и кеши

Comment: Создавал новый перед оформлением вопроса, всё то же самое

Comment: На телефоне в настройках разработчика разрешили отладку?

Comment: Да, в вопросе писал, что разрешил.